# How do I concatenate strings in arduino?

Tags: arduino

sorry I am a bit rusty here, how do I concatenate these 2 outputs?

display.println(timeinfo->tm_hour);
   display.println(timeinfo->tm_min);

Comment: use `print()` instead of using `println()`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want them to appear in the output one after another on the same line then use print instead of println for the first one.  Println adds a newline to the end of the output and print doesn't.  It's always good to look stuff like that up before using a function.

If you really want them put together into one string then you will have to show where those strings are coming from.  If they are String class objects you can just use + to put them together.  If they are proper c-style strings then you will need to use strcat.

Answer (score 0):

How are defining them?

- If you have initialized as arrays of characters:

**Example:** `char exampleCString[50] = "This is a C string";`

Then you can use `strcat()` function in C:

`strcat(str1,str2);`

**Note:** *Make sure "str1" buffer is big enough, because the result goes there.*

- If on the other hand, you have initialized your strings as objects of String class:

**Example:** `String exampleJavaString="This is a Java String example"`

Then just use the `+` operator to add them:

`str1=str1+str2`: